# Which gradle plugin do I install on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to follow a simple tutorial with an API called Twilio (https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms#overview) and to do that I need to start a gradle project in eclipse.

My eclipse isn't working on my linux partition so I am starting from scratch in a virtual machine.

I tried to install the gradle plugin in eclipse using the source URL http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4 but I'm not sure which modules to include and which not to.

I tried installing "Gradle IDE" and "Eclipse Platform" but it does not give the option to create a new gradle project, only "Gradle (STS) Project" which when selected does not look the same as in the tutorial.

Can someone explain what I need to do? My eclipse version is 3.8.1

edit: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUI8u.png) is what it looks like right now

Answer (score 0):

I am on Eclipse Mars version and the best way to install Gradle or any external plugin is from Eclipse Marketplace.

Navigation : Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... (the last sub-menu)

There you can search for 'gradle' and install Buildship gradle integration 2.0. After install eclipse will ask for restart and plugin gets installed successfully. You can import gradle project into eclipse afterwards.

Hope this helps.

[image: Eclipse Marketplace]

Comment: I don't have that option on mine. See the link I added

Comment: There is another way to install the plugin from eclipse marketplace site. Here is link. Hope will work for you http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration#group-details